# How do I edit all autostart applications?

Tags: unity, autostart

In Ubuntu 13.10 only very few applications are managed by the **Startup Applications** application:

[image]

How do I access for example the bluetooth indicator?

[image]

---

Is there a gui alternative to editing the config files in

```
/etc/xdg/autostart/
```

and

```
 ~/.config/autostart/
```

?

Comment: I am not sure I understand you well, is your question how to ad an application to autostart by gui? In that case.... you are looking at it.

Comment: no, I want to removo apps that are not listed here

Comment: @rubo77 are you sure the issue is about bluetooth? Can you show us an image of the applet you want to remove just in case?

Comment: I added a screenshot. and see xangua's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Show Hidden Startup Apps:**

```
sudo sed -i "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g" /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop
```

**4 Tricks to Speed Up Ubuntu**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwBoHZuauL8

Comment: that's better, but why isn't bluetooth showed there still???